# YouTube API v3 – Check if uploaded video has finished processing

Tags: php, youtube

I'm using the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) with the [Google PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and I managed to successfully upload videos and retrieve details. However, **I'd like to know when YouTube has finished processing the uploaded videos and they are ready to use**.

```
// The code is largely stripped down
$client = new Google_Client();
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet", array('id' => 'xyz'));
```

The `$listResponse` is an array containing just one video object (because just one video ID was requested) of type `Google_Service_YouTube_Video`, but none of the properties seem to hold useful information about the video processing status.

These are what I think to be the most interesting properties from `$listResponse[0]`

```
[processingDetailsType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_VideoProcessingDetails (string)
[processingDetailsDataType:protected] => (empty)
[processed:protected] => Array ([snippet] => 1)
```

Particularly interesting are `processingDetailsType` which is just a string of representing a class name, and `processed` which doesn't change after the video is successfully processed by YouTube.

The `$listResponse[0]['snippet']` holds the video details, but still nothing useful to determine if it has been processed or not. I monitored the `publishedAt` property, hoping it would change when the video was processed, but it stays the same. Again, the `processed` property, which seemed interesting, is always empty.

```
[snippet] => Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => tags
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

    [categoryId] => 22
    [channelId] => XXXYYYZZZ
    [channelTitle] => Some Channel Title
    [defaultLanguage] => 
    [description] => 
    [liveBroadcastContent] => none
    [localizedType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_VideoLocalization
    [localizedDataType:protected] => 
    [publishedAt] => 2015-04-15T14:54:47.000Z
    [tags] => 
    [thumbnailsType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails
    [thumbnailsDataType:protected] => 
    [title] => Some Video Title
    [modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [thumbnails] => Array
        (
            [default] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xyz/default.jpg
                [width] => 120
                [height] => 90
            )

            [medium] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xyz/mqdefault.jpg
                [width] => 320
                [height] => 180
            )

            [high] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xyz/hqdefault.jpg
                [width] => 480
                [height] => 360
            )

            [standard] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xyz/sddefault.jpg
                [width] => 640
                [height] => 480
            )
        )

        [localized] => Array
        (
            [title] => Some Video Title
            [description] => 
        )
    )

    [processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google API:

"[T]he snippet property contains the channelId, title, description, tags, and categoryId properties", there isn't nothing about proceessing data.

Instead if you use "processingDetails" you will get: "processingStatus", "processingProgress", processingProgress.partsTotal, ect", so its better to use

```js
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("processingDetails", array('id' => 'xyz'));
```

And you will get that data. In this link you can see the description: [https://developers.google.com/YouTube/v3/docs/videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this extra parameter: processingDetails
I have not tested yet, but I think it will work.

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet,processingDetails", array('id'=>'xyz'));
```

When you get the response, check processingStatus node
==> status.uploadStatus node 
if returns "uploaded"(still uploading) or "processed"(processing terminated ok).

At least this is the normal behaviour of the Youtube API v3 on the Javascript side and 
I expected to be the same or similar for PHP environment.
I hope help you.
If it works, please report it as a good answer.

Comment: Did some testing on my older videos, and it seems the API returns `"processingDetails": {"processingStatus": "terminated"}` for them, while a newly-uploaded video shows a status of "succeeded".